TeX4ht: footnotes that reset per page get mixed up
I want to create footnotes that reset per page (think of translators' footnotes that are labeled by *, **, ... but are not global in a chapter).
I set it up with perpage but when I generate HTML by TeX4ht I get mixed up results.
MWE
mwe.tex:
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[symbol*]{footmisc}

\usepackage{perpage}

\DefineFNsymbols{asterisks}{{\textasteriskcentered}{\textasteriskcentered\textasteriskcentered}{\textasteriskcentered\textasteriskcentered\textasteriskcentered}}

\setfnsymbol{asterisks}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\MakePerPage{footnote}

\begin{document}
    Lalalalal1.\footnote{some notes by translators}
    
    Lalalalal2.\footnote{some other notes by translators}
    
    \lipsum
    
    Lalalalal3.\footnote{some notes by translators on page 2}

    Lalalalal4.\footnote{some other notes by translators on page 2}
\end{document}

Compiled with
$ make4ht -l mwe.tex

Output
The first two footnotes are generated correctly but the trouble shows up at the fourth footnote:

The actual footnote text shows up after the footnote mark ** and the link is wrong: it points to the second footnote on page 1.
Desired output
The link of the fourth footnote points to a page with the text "some other notes by translators on page 2" and this text doesn't show up directly after the footnote mark.
How can I fix this?

The problem here is that the footnote counter is  reset after every page. TeX4ht bases links to footnotes on the counter, so it gets messed up. A solution is to introduce a separate counter, that will be unique for each footnote. Try this version of footmisc.4ht:
% footmisc.4ht (2024-06-20-14:04), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2019-2024 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2024-06-20-14:04}

\newcounter{:footnotes}

\def\FNnum{\the\:footnotes}

\HRestore\footnote

\def\:tempc{%
   \HAssign\FNnum = \csname c@:footnotes\endcsname%
   \stepcounter{:footnotes}%
   \HAdvance\FNnum by 1%
   \o:footnote:%
}
\HLet\footnote=\:tempc

\long\def\@footnotetext#1{\leavevmode
   \vbox{%\IgnorePar
      \leftskip0pt {\ht:everypar{}\parindent0pt\leavevmode}%
      \long\def\:tempc##1{\protected@edef\@currentlabel{\the\csname c@footnote\endcsname}%
\anc:lbl f{footnote}%
\Configure{newlabel}{\cur:th\the\csname c@footnote\endcsname}{\protect\p@footmisc@footnote{\the\csname c@footnote\endcsname}}
\a:footnotetext
   \o:@makefntext:{\b:footnotetext \csname a:footnotebody\endcsname
                {##1}\csname b:footnotebody\endcsname}\c:footnotetext
}%
\HLet\@makefntext\:tempc
%
      \reset@font\footnotesize
      \color@begingroup
        \@makefntext{\ignorespaces#1}%
      \color@endgroup
      \ht:special{t4ht@[}}\ht:special{t4ht@]}}


% detect if the symbol or symbol* option were used
% we can detect that by testing of \thefootnote macro

\edef\footmisc:thefootnote{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\thefootnote}}
\edef\footmisc:symbol{\unexpanded{\fnsymbol{footnote}}}
\edef\footmisc:symbolstar{\unexpanded{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}}

\ifx\footmisc:thefootnote\footmisc:symbol
  \newcommand\p@footmisc@footnote[1]{\@fnsymbol{#1}}
\else
  \ifx\footmisc:thefootnote\footmisc:symbolstar
    \newcommand\p@footmisc@footnote[1]{\@fnsymbol{#1}}
  \else
    \newcommand\p@footmisc@footnote[1]{\p@footnote{#1}}
  \fi
\fi



\Hinput{footmisc}
\endinput

The result looks and works fine:

